# Azure Websites WAWS and several subdomains

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, azure, http-status-code-404

I have a website
***mysite.azurewebsites.net***
and a domain ***mydomain.com***

Linking mydomain.com to the website succeded. 
I added a DNS entry A record and the awverify.mydomain.com CNAME to mysite.azurewebsites.net

Now,

http://mydomain.com works well

http://anything.mydomain.com returns a 404 error
(including www)

I would like to better understand how it works in terms of DNS settings and WAWS verification.

- Do I have to tell Azure about EVERY subdomains I would like to link
  to my website ?
- Then, what if I want to redirect *anything*.mydomain.com to my
  website ? Is that possible ?
- Isn't the DNS entry "awverify.mydomain.com" enough proof that I am
  the rightful owner of  the domain and all subdomains ?
- I mean : do I have to set up every awverify CNAME entry ?

Thanks for any clue on this ...